# How to proceed sending email aspx.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I have written a code for a contact page allowing users to type in 4 text boxes and then using these details to send an email from a gmail account. However, I have an error where I don't know how to fix where the code won't read email addresses in the text box. Thanks for your time and thanks for your help in advance!

html

```
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="nameContactUsTextBox" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="boring" ToolTip="Enter Name" Width="441px"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Name is required" ControlToValidate="nameContactUsTextBox"
                    Text="*"
                    Forecolor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>           
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="boring">E-Mail</td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="emailContactUsTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="boring" 
                    ToolTip="Enter Email" Width="443px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="E-Mail field is required" ControlToValidate="emailContactUsTextBox"
                    Text="*"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    Forecolor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email" 
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ControlToValidate="emailContactUsTextBox" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="boring">Subject</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="subjectContactUsTextbox" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="boring" ToolTip="Enter Subject" Width="441px"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Subject is required" ControlToValidate="subjectContactUsTextbox"
                    Text="*"
                    Forecolor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>           
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="boring" style="vertical-align:top">Comments</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="commentTextBox" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="boring" ToolTip="Enter Comment" Width="448px" Height="150px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                    ></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Comments are required" ControlToValidate="commentTextBox"
                    Text="*"
                    Forecolor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>           
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:ValidationSummary HeaderText="Please fix the following errors:" 
                    Forecolor="Red" ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="classic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="thankYouLabel" Font-Bold="True" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>



    try //indented
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("emailContactUsTextBox.Text");
            mailMessage.To.Add("moderator.ad.badshopblog.a2@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = subjectContactUsTextbox.Text;

            mailMessage.Body = "<b>Sender Name : </b>" + nameContactUsTextBox.Text + "<br/>"
                + "<b>Sender Email : </b>" + emailContactUsTextBox.Text + "<br/>"
                + "<b>Comments : </b>" + commentTextBox.Text + "<br/>";

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("moderator.ad.badshopblog.a2@gmail.com", "");
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            thankYouLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            thankYouLabel.Text = "Thank you for contacting us.";

            nameContactUsTextBox.Enabled = false;
            emailContactUsTextBox.Enabled = false;
            subjectContactUsTextbox.Enabled = false;
            commentTextBox.Enabled = false;
            submitButton.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: what is the error? give complete error details

Comment: When user enters an email in the email textbox and the other three textboxes the code will still not run. Am I missing something for the email tier?

Comment: so please use break point and debug, find the error so that we can help you. It's not easy for people in here to go through and guess issues in the code.

Comment: O that's right I forgot you can do that sorry

Comment: @mskimm please kill me if that's the edit you have done and called the code a javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is this line:

```
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("emailContactUsTextBox.Text");
```

It should be:

```
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailContactUsTextBox.Text);
```

Also, better logging would probably help here - write exceptions to a log file, and understand the problems from there.